# Length of a char array

Tags: c++

I have the code like this:

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <fstream.h>
void main()
{
    char dir[25], output[10],temp[10];
    cout<<"Enter file: ";
    cin.getline(dir,25);           //like C:\input.txt
    ifstream input(dir,ios::in);
    input.getline(output,'\eof');
    int num = sizeof(output);
    ofstream out("D:\\size.txt",ios::out);
    out<<num;
}
```

I want to print the length of the output. But it always returns the number 10 (the given length) even if the input file has only 2 letters ( Like just "ab"). I've also used strlen(output) but nothing changed. How do I only get the used length of array?

I'm using VS C++ 6.0

Comment: Unrelated, but main should return an `int`, not `void`.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` operator on array gives you size allocated for the array, which is `10`.
You need to use `strlen()` to know length occupied inside the array, but **you need to make sure the array is null terminated**.

With C++ better alternative is to simple use: **`std::string`** instead of the character array. Then you can simply use **`std::string::size()`** to get the size.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` always prints the defined size of an object based on its type, not anything like the length of a string.

At least by current standards, your code has some pretty serious problems. It looks like it was written for a 1993 compiler running on MS-DOS, or something on that order. With a current compiler, the C++ headers shouldn't have `.h` on the end, among other things.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string dir, output, temp;

    std::cout<<"Enter file: ";
    std::getline(cin, dir);           //like C:\input.txt
    std::ifstream input(dir.c_str());
    std::getline(input, output);
    std::ofstream out("D:\\size.txt");
    out<<output.size();
}
```

Comment: yes. it is 6.0 version. maybe of the 1990s :D
I'll try this. Thank you!

Comment: @TranHoaiNam: While VC++ 6 is certainly old, it's current enough to handle what's above.

Answer (score 0):

The `getline` that you are using is an *unformatted input function* so you can retrieve the number of characters extracted with `input.gcount()`.

Note that `\e` is not a standard escape sequence and the character constant `\eof` almost certainly doesn't do what you think it does. If you don't want to recognise any delimiter you should use `read`, not `getline`, passing the size of your buffer so that you don't overflow it.